# What can I do with my old iPhone

Tags: iphone

I currently use my iPhone 3G for testing my apps, but I am thinking about upgrading to the iPhone 4.  What can I do to my 3G so I can still use it for testing.  I don't need it to have 3G access, I just want to be able to put apps on it for performance testing since it is a slower device.  I would still like to keep Wi-Fi access if possible.  What options do I have?

Comment: The only real option you have is to donate it to charity...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pretty sure once you move your phone over to a new contract, your old phone will still continue to work over wireless and also for testing apps. It just won't work as a phone or have 3g access. I did this for a while before giving my old phone to a friend.

Answer (score 0):

Once your new iPhone is set up with your phone service provide, remove the SIM card from the old one. That's all you have to do. Actually you can probably work even with the SIM card in. Really, there's nothing to do.

Answer (score 0):

My old iPhone 3G and 3GS continue to work normally (except for cellular services) after I purchased new iPhones (with new SIM cards) and transfered my account to them.

Wifi and all installed apps work as well.

So you probably don't need to do anything at all.

If you upgrade the OS on any of these old iPhones, you may need to keep an old SIM card in them, so don't throw the old ones away.